# java swagger example String post body

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web, swagger

I am documenting a project through of swagger and I have a problem. I have many methods that uses  "@RequestBody String json", that I receive the body of post though a String.

I would like to show a "example" of the String that I am expecting though:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Lista os riscos de um paciente.")
@RequestMapping(value = "/pacienteRiscoFiltro/{token}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "text/plain" })
public RetornoPaginadoDTO postPacienteRiscoFiltro(
        @ApiParam("Body of post") @RequestBody String json) {
    //... code of method
}
```

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qlk4.png)

I would to change of "String" to any other text.

Someone have any idea how can I do this?

Comment: as an aside I think you want `consumes = { "application/json" }`

Comment: I receive a String, I just want display to who reads the documentation a example of how to send the String.

Comment: Did you look `@ApiParam`  ?

Comment: I looked, I tried:

@ApiParam(value = "Description", example="Hello world") @RequestBody String json

The "description" is displayed but example not.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Did you change the title or body of the question?
It seems the same to me.
I apologize, my english if very bad and I have difficulty in express me in english.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try something like: `@ApiOperation(value = "Save user details", response = User.class)`

[image: Api Operation example image]

If you wanna, you can get more details on https://sdngeeks.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/swagger-example-with-java-spring-apache-cxf-jackson/

Best Regards.

Comment: But what I want is to put a example in the text area with the pattern of input that I was waiting. A example to parameter @RequestBody String json.

Comment: Eduardo, this String json that you wanna use as a template is an object? because I use something like that in an old project: @Path("/inserir")
 @ApiOperation(value = "Inserir um usuario no sistema", response = Usuario.class)
 public Response cadastrarUsuario(@ApiParam(value = "{'Objeto': Usuario", required = true) String userParam)

Comment: Do you put the body of json in description field, is it?

Comment: Evandro, yes or something like @RequestBody UserDTO userDTO. By adding this, the object model will appear on swagger example box. And if you click on it, will paste to parameter box.